# How to justify that due to unique factorisation $d(d + 2b) = b\times b $ where $0<d<b$ has no solution in integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How (if it is even possible) to justify that due to unique factorisation  $d(d + 2b) = b\times b $ where $0<d<b$ has no solution in integers?

PS : It is possible to prove this using irrationality of $\sqrt 2$, but I am trying to avoid that and use unique factorisation.

Comment: HINT: $(b+d)^2=2b^2$ and $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

Comment: @Nilan damn, I added the post script too late, sorry

Comment: Consider $b^2=d(b+d).$ If $b$ and $d$ has no common factors both $d$ and $b+d$ should be perfect squares.

Answer (score 1):

Using unique factorization, we can write $d=2^{a_0}3^{a_1}5^{a_3}...$ and $b=2^{b_0}3^{b_1}5^{b_3}...$

We let $u=2^{min(a_0,b_0)}3^{min(a_1,b_1)}5^{min(a_2,b_2)}...$

First, we know $u|d$ because every prime factor of $u$ has less or equal than $d$, we also know $u|b$ for similar reason.

Now lets consider $d=ud_0$ and $b=ub_0$ where we have just shown $d_0$ and $b_0$ are integers.

Consider the unique factorization of $d_0$ and $b_0$, we know that for any prime number $p$, the power of $p$ in either $d_0$ or $b_0$ must be $0$ because $min(a_i,b_i)$ is equal to either $a_i$ or $b_i$.

The equation $d(d + 2b) = b\times b$ now becomes $d_0(d_0 + 2b_0) = b_0\times b_0$.

(1) If there exist a prime number $p$ where the power of $p$ in $b_0$ is $0$ and the power of $p$ in $d_0$ is not $0$, then the right side has power of $p$ equals $0$ while the left side has power of $p$ greater than $0$. Contradiction.

(2) If there exist a prime number $p$ where the power of $p$ in $d_0$ is $0$ and the power of $p$ in $b_0$ is not $0$, then let that power be $r$, we have the right side has power of $p$ equals $2r$. And since $d_0$ has power of $p$ equals $0$, $d_0+2b_0=c$ must have power of $p$ equals $2r$.

Now, since $b_0$ has power of $p$ equals $r$ and thus $2b_0$ has at least $r$ as well, we know $c-2b_0$ must have power of $p$ at least $r$ by factorizing $p^r$ out. However since $d_0=c-2b_0$ and the power of $p$ in $d_0$ is $0$, contradiction.

So all prime factors of both $b_0$ and $d_0$ must all have power $0$, forcing $b_0=d_0=1$, however $1(1+2)\neq 1\times 1$, contradiction. QED.